# Why will UIComponent not show content?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder, mxml

The code below works. However, If I change the container in the component from a Canvas to a UIComponent the Canvas inside the container does not show. Why is this the case?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute" xmlns:local="*">
    <local:Comp  />
</mx:Application>
```

Comp.mxml

```
<mx:Canvas   xmlns:mx = "http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"  buttonMode="true" useHandCursor="true"  >
    <mx:Canvas  width="100" height="100" backgroundColor="0xffff00"  />
</mx:Canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the UIComponent does not implement a measure() or updateDisplayList() method, and therefore your component is never given a size; thus there is no visual display area for the child component to be shown.

Please read up on the [Flex Component LifeCycle](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=ascomponents_advanced_2.html)

Comment: You stated that UIComponent does not use updateDisplayList. I'm using a Skin to style an HSlider and it uses updateDisplayList without a problem. The skin is a UIComponent. Does that make your answer wrong or is there another explanation?

Comment: @SimonRH You are misconstruing what I Said.  I said that the UIComponent class does not **implement** an updateDisplayList() method.  It does have one, bit there is no code inside the method.  An HSlider extends UIComponent, and most likely has code implemented in an overriden updateDisplayList() method. However, in the Spark Architecture, things can get confusing because updateDisplayList() code may be in a layout class or a skin class and not in the main class [like in the MX architecture]

Comment: I did not intend to misconstrue your statement. My question was merely that; a question. Thank you for your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the quotation from the UIComponent spec:

> The UIComponent class is not used as an MXML tag, but is used as a base class for other classes.

For details, see UIComponen specification here:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/UIComponent.html